# Having trouble converting this line of vb code into C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, preprocessor-directive

I have a vb.net project I'm trying to convert into C#. I have a file named MyWebExtension.vb and in it there is this line of code `#If _MyType <> "Empty" Then`

I attempted to convert into C# `#if (_MyType != "Empty")`

When I run the application I get the following error:

> Invalid preprocessor expression.

What did I do wrong with my conversion?

Comment: Ben show the full VB line of Compiler Directive Code please..

Comment: are you missing something like this Ben
`#if _MyType != "Empty"
#endif`

Comment: what is the type of variable _MyType....?

Comment: There is no need for full code, this kind of conversion wont work

Comment: #If _MyType <> "Empty" Then

Namespace My
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Module used to define the properties that are available in the My Namespace for Web projects.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    <Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.HideModuleName()> _
    Module MyWebExtension
        //some code here
     End Module
End Namespace

#End If

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From **[Compiler Error CS1517](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ey1471zb%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)**

The following sample shows some valid and invalid preprocessor expressions:

```
#if symbol      // OK
#endif
#if !symbol     // OK
#endif
#if (symbol)    // OK
#endif
#if true        // OK
#endif
#if false       // OK
#endif
#if 1           // CS1517
#endif
#if ~symbol     // CS1517
#endif
#if *           // CS1517
#endif

class x
{
   public static void Main()
   {
   }
}
```

So I think you can use like this;

```
#define _MyType

#If _MyType
```

From **[#if](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)**

> When the C# compiler encounters an #if directive, followed eventually
>   by an #endif directive, it will compile the code between the
>   directives **only if the specified symbol is defined**. Unlike C and C++,
>   you cannot assign a numeric value to a symbol; the #if statement in C#
>   is Boolean and only tests whether the symbol has been defined or not.

```
#define DEBUG
// ...
#if DEBUG
    Console.WriteLine("Debug version");
#endif
```

> **You can use the operators == (equality), != (inequality) only to test
>   for true or false . True means the symbol is defined**. The statement
>   -#if DEBUG has the same meaning as #if (DEBUG == true). The operators && (and), and ||   > (or) can be used to evaluate whether multiple symbols
>   have been defined. You can also group symbols and operators with
>   parentheses.

Comment: Soner if  a pre-processor directive then he would need the `#` otherwise why use it in the first place..??

Comment: -1 You cannot just change a preprocessor directive to a regular if statement and expect it to work.

Answer (score 2):

`#define` in C# can only specify 'flags', not constant values as VB allows you to do.

In C#, you can have:

```
#define _MyType

#If _MyType
```

or:

```
#if ! _MyType
```

but in VB, you can have:

```
#Const _MyType = "SomeType"

#If _MyType = "SomeType"
```

There is no good work-around for this - you can use constants, but of course these can only be referenced from within a class.